# Stuck inside infinite loop

Tags: java, string, loops, infinite-loop

The program is to print characters at position in multiples of N until last character is printed. If N goes beyond last character it navigates in cyclic manner until last character is printed. So here is my code in Java.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str=sc.next();
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int l=str.length();
        while(n!=l){
            System.out.print(str.charAt(n-1));
            n+=n;
            if(n>l)
                n-=l;
        }
    }
}
```

The program got inside a infinite loop and i'm not able to figure out where the logic went wrong. Help out!

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger and look at the values?

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer , i did step through the code after your suggestion and now i figured out where it went wrong. Yet 1 test case failed :(

Comment: Thanks @user16320675 , will try the code with for loop

Answer (score 0):

In you code you multiply `n` by `2` and subtract `1`.

For any `n>1` this series is infinitely increase. You should get exception when `n` become bigger then size of `str`.